# ReactJS Firebase retrieving URLs of bulk uploaded images

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a state where I store an array of images. I then iterate through the array and upload each image to Firebase. I'm trying to run getDownloadURL() on each iteration, but it keep returning an empty array. Can someone explain why? I thought firebase.storage would return a promise?

```
const[images, setImage] = useState([]);
const storage = firebase.storage();

const uploadImages = (arr) => {

        const storageRef = storage.ref();

        arr.forEach( image => {
            const uploadRef= storageRef.child(`productImages/${image.name}`).put(image)
            uploadRef.on(
                    "state_changed",
                    snapshot => {
                        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                    },
                    error => {console.log(error)},
                    () => {
                        storage.ref("productImages").child(image.name).getDownloadURL()
                        .then( console.log(url) );
                    })
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add it as a function

```
 () => {
                        storage.ref("productImages").child(image.name).getDownloadURL()
                        .then( url => console.log(url) );
                    })
```